# The div disapears when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select form with 7 options. According to the selected options, one of the divs will be displayed ( I have done this using jquery).

```
    <select class="form-control" id="select-1" style="width: 70%;margin: 0 
    auto;">
                <option selected disabled>Choose a product..</option>
                <option value="img-upload">Pencil art</option>
                <option value="img-upload">Oil painting</option>
                <option value="img-upload">Digital painting</option>
                <option value="img-upload">Invert art</option>
                <option value="typography-select">Typography</option>
                <option value="photo-restoration-select">Photo Restoration</option>
            </select>
```

If I select first 4 options, a div with class img-upload is displayed. This div is used to upload the images.

```
<div class="img-upload" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="row">
                <?php echo $image_view ?>      
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="center-block">
                    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" style="margin: 10px auto;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" class="btn btn-default center-block img-upload-btn" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    <?php echo $error_msg."".$success_msg ?>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When the button is clicked to upload the image, the php script runs to check whether file is image or not.

```
<?php
$error_msg = "";
$success_msg = "";
$image_view = "";
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="text-center" style="color:red;">File is not an image.Please upload a valid image format.</p>';
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $error_msg .= "";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $success_msg .= '<p class="text-center" style="color:green;">Your photo has been uploaded.</p>';
        $image_view .= '<img src="'.$target_file.'" alt="Cover" class="img-responsive center-block" style="height: 250px;width: auto;">';
        } else {
          $success_msg .= '<p class="text-center" style="color:red;">Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.Please try again later.</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The jquery to show and hide divs based on selected option:

```
$('.img-upload').hide();
        $('.typography-select').hide();
      $('.photo-restoration-select').hide();
        $(function() {
        $('#select-1').change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "img-upload") {
                $('.img-upload').show();
                $('.typography-select').hide();
                $('.photo-restoration-select').hide();
            }else if ($(this).val() == "typography-select") {
                $('.typography-select').show();
                $('.img-upload').hide();
                $('.photo-restoration-select').hide();
            }else if ($(this).val() == "photo-restoration-select") {
                $('.photo-restoration-select').show();
                $('.img-upload').hide();
                $('.typography-select').hide();
            }
        });
        });
```

The problem is, when the page loads, the select is appeared.If I select one of the first four options, the .img-upload div should be displayed.(It's displayed when I select any of first four options, no issues with that.)

But when I try to choose image and press upload, the .img-upload div is disapeared.

I have tried to solve this but couldn't fins a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda weird implementation you got there (why not capture the current selected options and toggle all it's siblings and vice versa).. but anyway, from a quick look I can tell you that you should handle this submit with ajax in case you dont want the DOM to be rendered again and load this first line of your jQuery that says *$('.img-upload').hide();* , and in fact hiding your div on every refresh.

Answer (score -1):

If you click  the submit button, the form will post to your server - most likely this is causing a page refresh and on page load, your jQuery will hide the .img-upload div.  Are you sure this is not posting correctly the way you would like?